# JavaFX capture events of a disabled button

Tags: user-interface, events, javafx

In my application I have a multi step form wizard in which
the next button is disabled unless all the required fields are entered.

Some fields require extra validation such as the directory picker,
for which I have to check whether the directory exists or not.

To ease the user experience I need to show an "Invalid directory" tooltip
next to the directory text field.

I would like to show the tooltips when the user tries to click/enter the disabled
next button.

Is it possible to capture events performed on a disabled button in JavaFX?

```
public void nextEntered(Event event) {
    Button button = (Button)event.getSource();
    if(button.isDisabled()){
        validate(currentTab);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disabledProperty "A disabled Node does not receive mouse or key events." So I think your best bet would be to check mouse position in the scene, and generate the tooltip if cursor is intersecting bounds of the button.

Comment: Why not validating the directory right after the selection? You could add a ChangeListener to the TextProperty of the InputField, or, if you use the JavaFX FileChooser, directly check if the folder exists.

Comment: @el_chupacabra That's what I did, I added an event listener to the scene and check whether the coordinates of the click are inside the bounds of the button. I was just wondering if there was a more elegant solution, apparently there isn't. Thank you.

Comment: @Rikan I already show the tooltip in the textfield's change event if the entered path is invalid. The problem is the user might not notice it immediately since if the user clicks somewhere else the tooltip will be removed and might wonder why he/she cannot progress to the next step. Maybe another solution would be to make the tooltip persistent until the field is valid. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to show a tooltip of a disabled field's value when the user moused over that disabled field.

I ended up putting a blank label over the disabled field and attaching a mouse event to that.

In the case of a button, you can just give the dummy label mouse transparency when the button becomes enabled so the user can click the button.

(You might even be able to bind the label's mouse transparency property to the button's enabled property but I'm not sure.)

I know this was asked a year ago but maybe it will help someone else.